# What is the correct way to close roll-down Ortlieb panniers?

Tags: panniers

What is the correct way to close Ortlieb [Front Roller](http://www.ortliebusa.com/prodInfo.asp?pid=30&cid=2) or [Back Roller](http://www.ortliebusa.com/prodInfo.asp?pid=31&cid=2) panniers?

There's a black plastic piece of plastic near the opening on the bag that is facing back if it is opened and unrolled that suggests to me that there is a correct direction. Should I roll them toward the back of the bag so the tab is covered with the very first roll or toward the front? Does it matter?

Comment: I doubt it matters, but maybe it’s a good idea to always roll in the same direction to avoid creating small cracks in the coating over long time. I roll backwards over the tab too, because it looks more neat ;)

Comment: @Michael Yes it matters.  If you roll to the font it does not stay rolled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rolled it to the front it would not look like that picture.  Yes you roll it to the back.  I have some Front Roller - not making this up.

Comment: This answer is actually more general than the OP might have thought: Looking at product images always seems to be a good idea in that kind of questions. For example, my Vaude panniers are rolled toward the side facing away from the bike (i.e. the opposite direction when compared to the Ortlieb ones). But this is also clearly visible in "official" images of them!